# How can global variables be accessed when using Multiprocessing and Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables

I'm trying to avoid having to pass variables redundantly into `dataList` (e.g. `[(1, globalDict), (2, globalDict), (3, globalDict)]`) and use them globally instead. `global globalDict` is not a solution to do so in the following code, however.

Is there a straightforward way to access data in a multiprocessing function globally?

I read the following [here](http://tding.in/2016/10/23/python-multiprocessing.html):

"**Communication is expensive.**
In contrast to communication between threads, exchanging data between processes is much more expensive. In Python, the data is pickled in to binary format before transferring on pipes. Hence, the overhead of communication can be very significant when the task is small. To reduce the extraneous cost, better assign tasks in chunk."

I'm not sure if that would apply here, but I would like to simplify data access in any case.

```
def MPfunction(data):
    global globalDict

    data += 1

    # use globalDict

    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    try:
        globalDict = {'data':1}

        dataList = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        data = pool.map(MPfunction, dataList, chunksize=10)

    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        pool.terminate()
```

Comment: Windows any unixy systems are very different this way. Which do you use?

Comment: Unix, Python 2.7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Linux, `multiprocessing` forks a new copy of the process to run a pool worker. The process has a copy-on-write view of the parent memory space. As long as you allocate `globalDict` before creating the pool, its already there. Notice that any changes to that dict stay in the child.

On Windows, a new instance of python is created and the needed state is pickled/unpickled in the child. You can use an initializing function when you create the pool and copy there. That's one copy per child process which is better than once per item mapped.

(as an aside, start the `try` block after creating the pool so that you don't reference a bad pool object if that's what raises the error)

```
import platform

def MPfunction(data):
    global globalDict

    data += 1

    # use globalDict

    return data

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    def init_pool(the_dict):
        global globalDict
        globalDict = the_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    globalDict = {'data':1}

    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count, init_pool(globalDict))
    else:
        pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

    try:
        dataList = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        data = pool.map(MPfunction, dataList, chunksize=10)
    finally:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Comment: Does that work also when `def MPfunction(data):` is in another module? I tried this, and the global variable is not defined...?

Comment: This is close except that this calls init_pool() on the parent process, not in the child processes, because you need to pass the args using initargs like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49343907/does-multiprocess-in-python-re-initialize-globals

Answer (score 0):

If all the objects you want to share between processes are read-only, you can declare these in the main thread (parent process) as global variables and share them with the child-processes as arguments.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global number
    number = 1000
    p = Process(target=my_method, args=(number))
```