# How to correctly use multiprocessing in this context?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

This is my first time trying concurrent programming and I need a little bit of help trying to tackle the problem.

I am trying to implement a learning-curve function like the one found in the sklearn.model_selection module on my own. I have two loops, one iterating over the number of samples to use (in this case a fraction [0,1] named *size_i*)and another on repeating the *fit_and_score* for each n_sample, **j** times.

The goal is to parallelize the *fit_and_score* function which gets passed the model, the n_samples, the training and test sets which will be scored and the scorer callable. The approach I have implemented (see code below) works fine, but is many times slower than the serial code I had before. I am assuming this is due to the overhead that comes from serializing all arguments passed to the *fit_and_score* function.

Since these arguments do not change over the **j** iterations I thought it must be possible to pass them once and thus reduce the serialization overhead. However, I cannot figure out a way to do so.

Here's my code:

```
def lc_fit_and_score(size_i, model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, scorer, strat):
    model_i = clone(model)
        if size_i == 1:
            #last iteration
            X_i, y_i = shuffle_in_unison_2d(X_train, y_train)
        else:
            X_i, _, y_i, _ = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, train_size=size_i, stratify=strat)
        model_i.fit(X_i, y_i.ravel())
        return scorer(model_i, X_i, y_i), scorer(model_i, X_test, y_test)

def learning_curve_mp(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, model, scorer, **kwargs):
    n_jobs = kwargs.pop('n_jobs', 1)
    n_jobs = len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)) if n_jobs==-1 else n_jobs
    n = kwargs.pop('n', 20)
    cv = kwargs.pop('cv', 10)
    y_window = kwargs.pop('y_window', None)
    test_idx = kwargs.pop('test_idx', []) 
    fname = kwargs.pop('fname', None)
    order = kwargs.pop('order', None)

    if kwargs:
        raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: {}".format(kwargs))

    strat = y_train if is_classifier(model) else np.array(y_train > 0, dtype=int)
    n_samples = []
    train_loss = np.zeros((n, cv))
    test_loss = np.zeros((n, cv))
    if n_jobs == 1:
        # serial version
        for i, size_i in enumerate(np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)[1:]):
            for j in range(cv):
                train, test = lc_fit_and_score(size_i, model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, scorer, strat)
                train_loss[i, j] = train
                test_loss[i, j] =  test
            n_samples.append(int(X_train.shape[0]*size_i))
    else:
        # parallel version
        for i, size_i in enumerate(np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)[1:]):
            pool = Pool(n_jobs, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(,))
            result_objects = [pool.apply_async(lc_fit_and_score, args=(size_i, model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, scorer, strat)) for x in range(cv)]
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            train_loss[i] = [x.get()[0] for x in result_objects]
            test_loss[i] = [x.get()[1] for x in result_objects]
            n_samples.append(int(X_train.shape[0]*size_i))
```

Ideally the loop that iterates over the number of samples can be parallelized as well, but I am also uncertain how to do that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: With the indentation you have at the moment both 'versions' will run.

Comment: Thanks @Neil for pointing that out. That was an error when copying the code. Obviously I don't want that. Fixed in Edit.

Comment: Have you tried using multiprocessing.Process() ?

Comment: @em_bis_me yes I did use *Process* initially. It did perform similary (as I was handing the same arguments)

Comment: I think for handling more than 2 arguments in apply_async(), you need to have 'kwds' or use partial function. Just try them once.

Answer (score 0):

So I looked around trying to find ways to reduce overhead and found this thread 
[How can global variables be accessed when using Multiprocessing and Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749801/how-can-global-variables-be-accessed-when-using-multiprocessing-and-pool)
It seems to be a hacky way of handling things and if anyone knows better feel free to share.

By rearranging the code from above to the following:

```
def lc_fit_and_score(size_i):
    X_train = global_obj['X_train']
    X_test = global_obj['X_test']
    y_train = global_obj['y_train']
    y_test = global_obj['y_test']
    model_i = clone(global_obj['model'])
    scorer = global_obj['scorer']
    strat = global_obj['strat']
    cv = global_obj['cv']
    train = np.zeros(cv)
    test = np.zeros(cv)
    for j in range(cv):
        if size_i == 1:
            #last iteration
            X_i, y_i = shuffle_in_unison_2d(X_train, y_train)
        else:
            X_i, _, y_i, _ = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, train_size=size_i, stratify=strat)
        model_i.fit(X_i, y_i.ravel())
        train[j] = scorer(model_i, X_i, y_i)
        test[j] = scorer(model_i, X_test, y_test)
    return train, test

def make_global(obj):
    global global_obj
    global_obj = obj

tmp = {'model': model,
       'X_train': X_train,
       'y_train': y_train,
       'X_test': X_test,
       'y_test': y_test,
       'scorer': scorer,
       'strat': strat,
       'cv': cv
      }

if n_jobs == 1:
   # serial version
   make_global(tmp)
   for i, size_i in enumerate(np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)[1:]):
       train, test = lc_fit_and_score(size_i)
       train_loss[i, :] = train
       test_loss[i, :] = test
       n_samples.append(int(X_train.shape[0]*size_i))
else:
   # parallel version - Note: huge overhead, only worth for CPU intensive model-fits
   pool = Pool(n_jobs, initializer=make_global, initargs=(tmp,))
   result_objects = pool.map(lc_fit_and_score, [size_i for size_i in np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)[1:]])
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   for i, result in enumerate(result_objects):
       train_loss[i, :] = result[0]
       test_loss[i, :] = result[1]
   n_samples = [int(X_train.shape[0]*size_i) for size_i in np.linspace(0, 1, n+1)[1:]]
del tmp
```

I achieved comparable performance to the serial version when testing with a LinearRegression model with a CV=100 and with a CV=1000 the parallel version is 2.4x faster. I am hoping that the difference between the serial and parallel version falls in favor of the parallel at lower CVs for more complicated models. So once the model fitting becomes the CPU limiting factor.